# what is the alternative to offsetLeft in internet-explorer (not work with me in ie)

Tags: javascript

My question is obvious, doesn't need to Clarify.

My code

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
                var elem = document.getElementById('box');
                evt = evt || window.event;
                var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
                switch (charCode) {
                    case 37:
                        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
                        elem.style.left = parseInt(elem.offsetLeft - 10) + 'px';
                        elem.innerHTML = elem.offsetLeft;
                        break;
                    case 38:
                        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
                        elem.style.top = parseInt(elem.offsetTop - 10) + 'px';
                        elem.innerHTML = elem.offsetTop;
                        break;
                    case 39:
                        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
                        elem.style.left = parseInt(elem.offsetLeft + 10) + 'px';
                        elem.innerHTML = elem.offsetLeft;
                        break;

                    case 40:
                        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
                        elem.style.top = parseInt(elem.offsetTop + 10) + 'px';
                        elem.innerHTML = elem.offsetTop;
                        break;
                    case 101:
                        elem.style.position = 'relative';
                        elem.style.left = 0 + 'px';
                        elem.style.top = 0 + 'px';
                        break;

                    default:

                }
            };
```

The previous example work fine in ff but not work in ie.

What is the reason of `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`  don't work in IE.
Is there an alternative to internet-explorer or so, what's the problem ?

---

### Try the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbDnT/) In jsfiddle.

Comment: It works in IE ... Even , i uses it

Comment: What error do you get ? Post the error ..

Comment: @The Dark Knight: Unfortunately, no errors

Comment: Then how do you know that this is root cause of the problem ?

Comment: @The Dark Knigh: This is what I doubt it, and This is just only doubt.

Comment: why are you using `parseInt` like that?

Comment: @The Dark Knigh: In order to does not happen surprise.

Comment: Do you have any spans in your html code ?

In case you have, consider adding position:relative style to the SPAN to get rid of the problem. Consult this URL : http://kirblog.idetalk.com/2007/10/problem-with-offsettop-and-element.html

Comment: Please show some basic html markup with the code that you are using. It would be nice to have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You can see the demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbDnT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a simple fix is changing the event you are listening for from keypress to keydown

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zp8bB/1/show/)